# Rails query object not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, autoloader, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a query object in Rails 5.2.2

#### app/queries/car_query.rb

```
class CarQuery
  attr_reader :relation
  # code
end
```

when I reference it in the console, I get

#### Error

> NameError (uninitialized constant CarQuery)

Since the folder/file is in the app directory, I thought it automatically gets loaded. Am I incorrect? If so, why would my form objects autoload and not these? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try running `bin/spring stop` in your console then restarting the app.

If that doesn't work add update you application.rb with

```
Spring.watch "app/queries/**"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the name of the file corresponds to the class name, or else rails will have trouble loading it. That is to say, make sure the file name is `car_query.rb`, if CarQuery is the name of the class.

**CarQuery.rb goes against rails naming conventions and will mess with autoloading.**